# How to add variant management in SAPUI5 project without using or embedding with smart table

Tags: sapui5

I have been trying to use variant management in my project, but not able to get any solution. Using smart table it is possible to get results, but the requirement is to use it without any smart controls.
I'm running my code on gateway server, problem is **save** button not **enabled** in **variant management**. Have attached screenshot of the same. Please provide me solution.

[Variant Management Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpCr1.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using any Standard Services or your custom service ?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3830843. it may be help ful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have used the above link's option. But no results. Is there any other way?